# Access response in Json

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

I am using the [JSON VBA library](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to parse a large JSON response but I can not access the elements of the response as expected.

For example the response has the structure:

```
{employees: [{employeeId: {id: 1234}, personNumber: "ABC123", shortName: "Bob",...},...],...}
```

I have tried :

```
Dim JsonPayload As Object
Set JsonPayload = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.ResponseText)


MsgBox JsonPayload("dict_pDictionary")
MsgBox JsonPayload("employees")(1)("employeeId")
```

And also :

```
Set emp = JsonPayload("employees")
For Each e In emp
    Debug.Print "employee", e.shortName
    Debug.Print "shortName", e
    Debug.Print "shortName", e.dict_pDictionary
Next e
```

The error is `Object Does not support this property or method.`

I would like to know how to loop over the response. Some are variant/object/dictionary and other parts seem to be variant/object/collection

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA JSON converts objects (`{}`) to Dictionaries, and Arrays (`[]`) to Collections.

In your code `e` is a Dictionary object, not an object with named properties, so:

```vb
Dim jso As Object, emps, e

Set jso = JsonConverter.ParseJson( _
  "{""employees"":[{""employeeId"": {""id"": 1234}, ""personNumber"": ""ABC123"", ""shortName"": ""Bob""}]}")

Set emps = jso("employees")
For Each e In emps
    Debug.Print e("employeeId")("id")  '>> 1234
    Debug.Print e("shortName")         '>> Bob
Next e
```